# Looking at std::unique_ptr and its nullptr_t constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr, nullptr

I am trying to understand why `unique_ptr` has a nullptr_t constructor

```
constexpr unique_ptr::unique_ptr( nullptr_t );
```

I had assumed this was because the normal one argument constructor was explicit and thus would reject the nullptr value:

```
explicit unique_ptr::unique_ptr( pointer p );
```

But when I build an example it compiler fine:

```
namespace ThorsAnvil
{
    template<typename T>
    class SmartPointer
    {
        public:
            SmartPointer()      {}
            explicit SmartPointer(T*){}
    };
}


template<typename T>
using SP    = ThorsAnvil::SmartPointer<T>;
int main()
{

    SP<int>     data1;
    SP<int>     data2(new int);  // fine
    SP<int>     data3(nullptr);  // fine
}
```

Here is the output:

```
> g++ --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.56) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0
Thread model: posix
> g++ -Wall -Wextra -std=c++11 SP1.cpp
```

Why does std::unique_ptr need the extra constructor that takes a nullptr_t argument?

Comment: My guess, pulled out of thin air, is for optimization because it's declared as `constexpr`.

Comment: Is the `nullptr_t` constructor also `explicit`?

Comment: @templatetypedef: No. Just contexpr.

Comment: This will fail: `SP<int> data; data = nullptr;`

Comment: @CrappyExperienceBye That might be your answer right there - it allows for direct assignment of `nullptr`. Is that a sufficient justification?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SP<int>     data3(nullptr);  // fine
```

You're using direct initialization which causes the `explicit` constructor to be considered. Try the following and your code won't compile

```
SP<int>     data4 = nullptr;
```

Now add the following constructor and the line above will compile

```
SmartPointer(std::nullptr_t){}
```

So the `nullptr_t` constructor makes a `unique_ptr` behave like a raw pointer in the case where you want to initialize it to `nullptr`, but avoids any surprising transfer of ownership in other cases where you might be actually assigning it a raw pointer.

Comment: `SP<int>   data5 = new int;` Also failes.

Comment: @CrappyExperienceBye And that one should fail, see the last paragraph I just added about "surprising" transfer of ownership.

Comment: So basically this is to allow `SP<int> newData = nullptr;` and there is an equivalent assignment version to allow `newData = nullptr;`. So we can easily reset the unqiue_ptr but not assign it ptrs accidentally.

Comment: @CrappyExperienceBye Yes, and not just initialization/assignment. Think of a function `void foo(unique_ptr<Type>) {...}` Clearly the function takes ownership of the argument. Say someone calls it as `Type *t = new Type; foo(t);` Having that compile and the function silently assume ownership is not desirable behavior.

Comment: Yes I understand about being explicit with `T*`. I just trying to see why it is useful to special case the `nullptr`.

Comment: @CrappyExperienceBye There's nothing to guard against in that case, the implicit conversion is safe. So it probably comes down to allowing you to get away with less typing and mimicking a raw pointer while also avoiding the downsides.